# App Store download progress doesn't go away after successful download

Tags: applications, mac-appstore, dock

Even after I successfully download any apps from App Store, the progress of that download doesn't go away from dock.

[image: Dock with download progress stuck]

How can I fix it?

The problem is on macOS High Sierra, 10.13.4.

Comment: Try restarting the Dock by running `killall Dock`.

Comment: This happens to me all the time, and in every version of macOS at least as far back as Yosemite. Restarting the Dock and/or Finder does not fix the problem, although fully rebooting my computer does. It can happen for any type of file being copied to a folder that's in the Dock, although not consistently.

Comment: @NimeshNeema It removes the status bar. But, appears next time something is installed or copied to the same folder.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy Yeah, you are right. I happens when anything is copied  into the folder too. I only seeing first time in High Sierra.I reinstalled my macOS and the problem disappeared.

Comment: @saneef I will be curious as to whether the problem is still fixed a couple months from now. I format my computer before every major macOS upgrade.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy - why on earth?? It's not Windows, it doesn't get bit-rot if you don't scrub it clean every 6 months. My current machine has direct lineage from 2001, migrate/update.

Comment: I had this issue once, turned off my Mac, did a PRAM reset and it went away

Comment: Does the progress bar actually show download animation  _when files are downloading_?

Comment: @IconDaemon Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Restart the Dock by executing: `killall Dock`.
2. Reset [NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204063).
3. Reset [SMC](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201295).

Resetting NVRAM clears the cache which generally causes the issue.

Comment: I reinstalled my macOS and this problem vanished. I can't verify right now :) . Since @Jules confirms this same fix, I'm marking this as answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can restart your Mac, Force Quit or delete Applications and restore the folder. Best: Upgrade to new OS

Comment: Can you clarify on what you mean by "upgrade to new OS"? @saneef stated that he is using the latest version of macOS.